# How do you set up a local dev environment to mimic production Ghost env on OpenShift?

Tags: git, openshift, development-environment, ghost-blog, ghost

I've set up a Ghost blog on OpenShift and found the process to be fairly straight forward. The site is up and running and I've even set up Jenkins for continuous integration when I need to push up changes.

I have yet to make any significant changes (just style updates thus far) because I can't figure out how to set up a test/development environment. How should I go about setting up an environment where I can test larger code changes before committing them to the main Git repo on OpenShift?

Is there a way to get the app running locally? I've tried just cd-ing to the app directory in my Terminal (on a Mac), but when I run npm start I get the following...

```
> openshift-ghost-quickstart@ start /path_to_my_app/dev/app
> node index

Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module '/path_to_my_app/dev/app/node_modules/ghost/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
```

*(node_sqlite3.node does exist there, BTW)*

What do I need to do to set it up so that I'm able to use the same codebase and repo, but see my changes locally, before actually committing them to the repo? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Try running `npm update` to get past the specific error you listed.

Comment: Thanks @mbaird! After running npm update, I now see the following when I run npm start:

> openshift-ghost-quickstart@ start /path-to-app
> node index

Migrations: Database initialisation required for version 003
Migrations: Creating tables...
Migrations: Creating table: posts
Unhandled rejection Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
    at Client_SQLite3.acquireRawConnection (/path-to-app/node_modules/ghost/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js:89:10)

Do you think it's just a matter of permissions or might I need to update some stuff in my config.js?

Answer (score 0):

This got me for a while as well. There are two things to do to get this working:

1. Install sqlite3 again under the node_modules/ghost/node_modules directory - by default it has the linux bindings from Openshift. You need the OSX binding
2. Create a **data** folder in the existing **content** folder.